# 4TB SATA SSD for iMac internal: Micron or Samsung?

Tags: desktop, ssd, sata

I'm looking to replace the 3TB HDD in my 27" iMac with an SSD of equal or greater size. Opening the case is fairly arduous and re-sealing it requires expensive consumables, so this is something I want to get right the first time.

I've had my eye on Samsung's 860 EVO 4TB SSD, currently [$600 from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07864XY8B). I'm pretty sure this would be a good choice. But today I saw Micron's 4TB 5100 ECO series, which is [$350 from OWC](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/Micron/AK3T8TBY1A/).

To my untrained eye these look pretty similar. Reviews of the Micron 5100 imply it's intended for enterprise use in servers, and don't talk at all about using it in consumer desktops.

Is there any reason to choose the significantly more expensive Samsung 860 EVO over the Micron? Or can someone recommend a different 4TB SSD that would be better?

Comment: Which year iMac is this?

Comment: @JMY1000 Retina 5k, 27-inch, Mid 2015

Comment: Would you be interested in retaining the HDD and installing an SSD in the existing slot? You'll also be able to get better performance, since it's an NVM-e drive.

Comment: @JMY1000 I'm interested, but is that even possible? For one I thought Apple used a proprietary form factor for their PCIe blade, and for another I'm not aware of any NVM-e drives greater than 3TB.

Comment: If you can live with 2TB, there are options, and I'd be happy to write up an answer. What's your use case? In general my recommendation would be to use a "more" moderate SSD, get a large HDD for mass storage, and cache as necessary on the SSD.